# How to make subitems on responsive menu always visible for mobile devices only using css in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm working on https://apostolosloukas.org website. The menu works fine in pc and android mobile phones. However, in iPhone 11 with iOS 14.6 the sub items of the menu are not visible even though we click on the parent item.

I'm not sure of how to fix this, but now I'm thinking to make always visible the submenu items in the hamburger (responsive) menu for mobile devices.

I'm working with `CSS`.

My current code is the following but is not working. Any help please?

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
 .dropdow-menu ul.li  {
    visibility: visible !important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following solution:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 769px) {
.navbar-collapse ul {
    display: block !important;
    visibility: visible !important;
    top: 100% !important;
    position:relative;
    }
}
```